# script#, generating code for referenced library

Tags: script#

I have a script# 'app' and an import library that wraps a js library. I reference the library from the app, all compiles OK. But no JS code is generated for the library. For example the library has a Record derived class, this requires that a .$create_foo_bar method be emitted into the app js; it is not. The app code refers to the generated code that does not exist

So , is this a bug? If not what do I do? Do I have to build the import library as another app and include its generated js? Is there a compiler switch to say "generate JS for the referenced assemblies too"?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the import library does not generates a .js at all. It is the Script Library that references the Import Library what generetes the .js files. So, I think you should have at least 3 projects, the Import Library (just proxy classes with empty members for the external library), the Script Sharp (that references the import library and has your own classes and generates the javascript files), and the Web application that uses the .js file (remember to reference in the web pages the library and the script sharp genereted javascript file)

Comment: thats exactly what I have and it doesnt work if the import library defines classes that need to have JS code generated for them (such as Record derivedtypes)

Comment: If you don't have existing script corresponding to what you're defining in an import library, then don't put that in the import library - put it instead in a regular script library, and then the compiler will in fact generate script for those.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring the type as a Record, I would configure it as:

```
[Imported]
[IgnoreNamespace]
[ScriptName("Object")]
public class ImportedRecordLikeType
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: right but there are other constructs that require JS to be emitted; this does nt address those cases

Comment: @pm100 Can you be more specific then? I haven't come across any inbetween cases.

Comment: the import library that I am using has static code in it that sets up event handlers. This emits JS code. It seems to me that the s# compiler should emit code for the referenced assemblies as well. This doesnt seem hard to do (but since we dont have the source of the compiler we dont know - although reflector let me peek a bit(

Comment: i also see that s# compiler will generate code for interfaces in the same way it generates code for records - found by peeking with reflector

Comment: I may still be missing something (feel free to email me a sample project setup though), but "S# compiler should emit code for the referenced assemblies as well" I don't think is what is normally expected conceptually. Building imports is meant to expose some other .js file's "public" objects to S#, not to introduce new logic. If you're trying to subclass a .js prototype from C#, I don't think this is cleanly supported. You'd have to do some runtime fixup yourself but not part of your imports.

Comment: but if there are constructs in the import library that require emitted js (record based classes, non-sealed classes, interfaces,...) then in fact the import library needs instead to be built as a s# 'app' library and have its JS independently included into  the page. This seems somewhat arbitrary. I need to know in advance what constructs require JS to be emitted and either not use them or instead not use the import library construct. For example I started with the extsharp extjs codeplex project. I set this up as an import library - but that doesnt work becuase it uses some of those features